# Should I make a Separate View For Each? Single View? How to Index?

Tags: json, sql-server, indexing, view

I trying to build a filtering system, where I got 10 different product types each with all with different specs(ram, hardrive capacity and etc).

Between all product types I got like 100 "specs" some are shared some are per product type.

I store all the different "specs" in json string in sql server 2017 which supports json.

```
{"modelNumber":"1421515","ram": 8}
```

now I want to index most of these fields in the json string as I have filters so I need fast lookup.

Should I make a view for each of these product types and basically index all the json fields? Or can I have one big view?

How would Index these fields in a view being they are in json?

Comment: My first question is going to be - Why store this information in JSON? If you're looking for a "Fast Lookup", JSON in SQL Server is unlikely going to be the fastest way to go.  Secondly, you can create computed columns in a table like the following: `ALTER Table TABLENAME ADD COLUMNNAME AS JSON_VALUE(JSONCOLUMN, '$.JSONVALUE') ` and you can easily index that.

Comment: Matt, you are correct. If performance is a factor (when isn't it?) then separate columns is the way to go.

Comment: @Matt - All common fields have there own column, but I don't want to make a table per product as this is always expanding nor do I want to have one table with 100 columns with half of them null depending on product. I was creating computed columns that are indexed but  a co-worker said this is going to slow down my inserts and I should make views. If you want to give me for future refrence how to not use Json in this situation great but it is too late to change and I got to make do with what I got.